# How to make custom file extension in java like .mylib .db .rmpdb?

Tags: java

I am going to develop RCP Desktop Software in which I have mechanism like Import/Export data for that if I export my data then one secured extension file should be created which I will be able to import in this tool only. Same like .java .sql .db ect. Steps or Code would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you just wanting to use an extension your program will recognize, or are you wanting the OS to recognize the extension and open it with your program?

Comment: No. I just want my tool can recognize only. No other tool should recognize because i want to make it very secured.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this
`File myFile = new File("myfile.rmpdb");`
You can then pass this file object to a Writer. Nothing actually stops you from having custom extensions. You can even have files which have no extensions.

However, as Pherion mentioned in the comment, the OS will not know how to handle this. Your program/tool will have full responsibility to know how to read/create this type of file.

Comment: In addition, for security, I'd suggest using Serialized objects.  That at least turns your stored file into a binary that people can't just open up and read the plain text.  Encryption would be a whole different discussion.

Comment: Thanks Mackiavelli, Pherion. Let me try out this way